# Problems while setting up an existing Laravel Project in a local machine on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, setup-project

[image: NotFoundException]I am new to laravel but having some PHP experience.

I am facing issues while setup the an existing laravel project in my local machine.

I have followed the steps from [this](https://gist.github.com/hootlex/da59b91c628a6688ceb1) reference link.

I am attaching the screenshot of the error.

I have tried to check the `routes/web.php` file and run the controller action manually but the same error is coming.

I have done `composer update` but no success.

This is my `routes/web.php`

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'Admin\AuthController@index');
    Route::get('/login', 'Admin\AuthController@index');
    Route::get('[![enter image description here][1]][1]/papers', 'Admin\PapersController@index');
    Route::get('/providers', 'Admin\ProvidersController@index');
    Route::get('/products', 'Admin\ProductsController@index');
});
```

This is my routes/api.php file

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');

$api->version('v1', function ($api) {
    $api->group(['middleware' => ['throttle:60,1', 'bindings'], 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function ($api) {
        $api->get('ping', 'Api\PingController@index');

        //$api->group(['middleware' => ['auth:api'], ], function ($api) {
        $api->group(['prefix' => 'papers'], function ($api) {
            $api->get('/', 'Api\PapersController@index');
            $api->post('/', 'Api\PapersController@store');
            $api->get('/{uuid}', 'Api\PapersController@show');
            $api->put('/{uuid}', 'Api\PapersController@update');
            $api->delete('/{uuid}', 'Api\PapersController@destroy');
        });

        $api->group(['prefix' => 'providers'], function ($api) {
            $api->get('/', 'Api\ProvidersController@index');
            $api->post('/', 'Api\ProvidersController@store');
            $api->get('/{uuid}', 'Api\ProvidersController@show');
            $api->put('/{uuid}', 'Api\ProvidersController@update');
            $api->delete('/{uuid}', 'Api\ProvidersController@destroy');
        });
```

This is my channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

This is my routes/console.php

```
Artisan::command('dev:generate-personal-token {userId}', function ($userId) {
    $user = \App\Entities\User::find($userId);
    $this->info('Token for user ' . $user->name);

    $token = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token')->accessToken;
    $this->info($token);
})->describe('Generates a personal access token for a user');
```

I want to setup this project any how please someone help me out.

Comment: what page are you looking for?

Comment: I want to run the project. Starting with homepage

Comment: did you define the route for home page ?

Comment: as i see you define all routes with admin prefix so you should start your link with admin

Comment: I have not done anything in this project. I am just setting up the one third party's existing laravel project in my local machine. So i don't aware of routes in this project. I just have share the routes which are defined in this project.

Comment: @AhmedAtoui Yes admin page is running by this url : http://localhost:8000/admin.But i want to run frontend.

Comment: is there are other routes except admin routes ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199319/discussion-between-php-guy-and-ahmed-atoui).

Comment: @phpguy can you send the whole routes file?

Comment: I have edited my questions and added route folder's files code. @AhmedAtoui and rkg.